# Recover deleted partition

Tags: partitioning, restore

I had recently installed ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS using the option replace windows xp using ubuntu. So all my partitions lost. But i had the very important contents and backups please help me how to retrieve the deleted partition. Pls help me.

its in my Office so pls help me guys.

Comment: Try testdisk - https://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_with_testdisk

Answer (score 0):

the fact that you installed ubunt over the old windows partition is bad news because you have over written the the data that was on the partition and the chances of recovering your work are very minimal

however try using `Hureins bootcd` its one of the best data recovery tools